# What is the difference between "to encourage" and "to call on"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, differences

For me, Russian speaking person, It is distinctively difficult to identify the difference in meaning between these two words within the context. Are these interchangeable?

The **encourage** has multiple meanings in Russian that makes it confusing for me.

> 1) I encourage you all to do well in your studies.
>
> 2) I call on all the people to not take action.

Comment: Have you googled the definitions of ***encourage*** and ***call on***? Please show the research you have done on this topic.

Comment: @Hank Sure I did. The thing is that encourage has several different meanings in Russian language so it's confusing for me.

Comment: If you did, then you need to make that apparent in your post. Show exactly what part confuses you. Say that it's the fact that it has multiple definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, encouragement is seen more of a support-type word. Encouraging someone to do something is giving positive reinforcement to a course of action.

From Google, the most pertinent definition in this comparison would be:

> give support and advice to (someone) so that they will do or continue to do something

To call on someone, however, is to directly challenge someone to do something. It has a more *active* connotation than to merely encourage someone

From Google, the most pertinent definition in this comparison would be:

> demand that (someone) do something.

---

Both are methods to manipulate behavior. Encouragement is through positive reinforcement, while calling on is through coercion.